# Efficient way to test for reaching max size of uint64_t C++

Tags: c++, performance

I have the a class with the following two class members:

```
uint64_t m_numOfOperations;   // how many times an operation was done
uint64_t m_someOtherMember;  // will be divided by m_numOfOperations
```

In some function, **updateNumberOfOperations()**, I increment this counter by one and divide m_someOtherMember by the counter (m_numOfOperations)y, like so:

```
m_someOtherMember = m_someOtherMember / m_numOfOperation;
```

Now, this function will be called lots of times, eventually will cause the ***numOfOperation*** to reach its maximum value , and then, in the next call , to reach zero - which ,at the moment will cause an error of dividing by zero.

Now, I guess that the following straight forward implementation will do the trick, yet, the check for zero for each UINT64_MAX times is somewhat not efficient.

So my question is – is there a more efficient way to achieve the functionality of the current implementation of my updateNumberOfOperations() method ?

Thanks,
Guy.

Current implementation of my class:

```
#include <cstdint>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        void updateNumberOfOperations()
        {
            if (UINT64_MAX == m_numOfOperations)
            {
                ++m_numOfOperations;
            }
            ++m_numOfOperations;
            m_someOtherMember = m_someOtherMember / m_numOfOperations;
        }

    private:
       uint64_t m_numOfOperations;   // how many times an operation was done
       uint64_t m_someOtherMember;  // will be divided by numOfOperations
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have the `if` before the first incrementation?

Comment: Also, what you're trying to achieve is unclear. If the value overflows, how is it still meaningful to your purpose?

Comment: If you increment a `uint64_t` once in nanosecond, it is going to take you ~584 years for it to wrap.

Comment: Have you heard of "branch prediction"? this condition will be near costless.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin cruel compilers like GCC can still screw you for not checking.

Comment: `<cstdint>` is not guaranteed to put its symbols in the global namespace; you should prefix them with `std::`. Also, stylistically it seems more C++-like to use `<limits>` and `std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()`.

Comment: @DavidHaim Wrapping unsigned numbers is well defined, unlike for signed.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin if the compiler can figure out you divide two variables without any zero-check it can trigger UB-driven optimizations.

Comment: @DavidHaim Integer division by 0 is UB. The compiler assumes it never happens. Feel free to provide a counter-example.

Comment: `m_someOtherMember` would be `0` after 21 times of`updateNumberOfOperations`

Comment: @appleapple How much would you bet on that? :)))

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin if `m_someOtherMember` never update it's value, call `updateNumberOfOperations` 21 times result it divide by `21!` which is larger than `2^64`

Comment: I know it's just an example, but just like other says this takes ~584 year to happened. This example is not realistic.

Comment: @Rotem - you are correct - fixed it, thanks for pointing that out !! Regarding your other question - this check is only to prevent a divided by zero scenario. If you have a total different approach to solve this "situation" I would love to hear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following function to increment an unsigned number with skipping 0 value on wrap:

```
inline uint64_t inc(uint64_t a) {
    ++a; // Wrapping unsigned numbers is well-defined. 
    return a + !a;
}
```

[It generates no branches in the code.](https://godbolt.org/g/NVkhB3)

Also note, that if you increment a `uint64_t` once in nanosecond, it is going to take you ~584 years for it to wrap.

Comment: It took me 3 mins to grasp this, then it felt like Harry Potter touched me with his wand!

Comment: @KhatamNaayak I learned this trick when reading z80 assembly of a ZX Spectrum game when I was 11 years old.